# Solaris 10 (U10) Live upgrade not working

Tags: solaris, solaris-10, sparc

I have a server that's currently running Solaris 10 (9/10), and I wanted to upgrade it to (8/11). It is on a SPARC system, with a ZFS mirrored pool.

I just installed solaris live upgrade pakages from the latest version (8/11), following the instructions on http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E23823_01/html/E23801/lucreate-8.html#scrolltoc

After I followed the instruction, installed the packages and patched, lucreate refuse to work. All I get is:

```
# lucreate -n zfsBE
lucreate: cannot execute
# lucreate
lucreate: cannot execute
```

Is there any way to actually see more debug message? I don't even know what I did wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What sort of platform are you installing on?  Sparc, or intel?

check that you installed the right architecture of liveupgrade package.

```
# file /usr/sbin/lucreate
/usr/sbin/lucreate:     ELF 32-bit MSB executable SPARC Version 1, dynamically linked, stripped

# pkginfo -l SUNWluu | grep ARCH
       ARCH:  sparc
```

That's what you'd expect to see on a sparc box.  The `cannot execute` error to me indicates that maybe the packages installed were for the other architecture than the one you have.

Comment: Oh dear! Yes, it's x86... I'm downloading the SPARC version now :-)

Answer (score 0):

Check you don't have an alias defined.  Also try which lucreate to check the path.